# ¿por qué una imagen no se ve en iphone 5s pero sí en movil LG antiguo?

Tags: css, responsive

he hecho mi pagina responsive pero una imagen no se ve en el iphone 5s, y sin embargo en mi otro movil mas viejo (LG) si se ve...cabe resaltar que la imagen esta como fondo de un contenedor, por eso sospecho que la version 5 del iphone puede no ser compatible con el metodo URL de css.. ¿como se podria solucionar esto? Dejo mi codigo:

```
@media ( max-width : 480px ) {
html {
background : #000 url( "i/back_min.jpg" ) no-repeat fixed center;
font-size  : 16px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser a causa del meta viewport?

o si lo tienes?

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport"/>
```

eso en tu etiqueta head

Comment: si lo tengo: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

Comment: el problema es el BACKGROUND-ATTACHMET:FIXED; y el BACKGROUND-SIZE:100%; que iphone 5 no reconoce.